# Build a custom Material Design Lite Palette

Tags: css, material-design, material-design-lite

How can i build a customized MDL with the colors that not are in this tool: https://getmdl.io/customize/index.html

I whant those colors:

Primary-color: red 400 (#EF5350)

Secondary-color: amber 500 (#FFC107)

That form part of color's app that I'm making:

[image: my app]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've read this following wiki: https://github.com/google/material-design-lite/wiki/Customizing-Colors

And I can change the variables with the custom color, then I build with "gulp", and find the CSS file in the "dist" directory.

Answer (score 1):

Visit the link you are getting by selecting 2 colors (remember which is main color) just select two. Than copy all the css code in a css file you created search and replace main- and second color with your color. Link your file in your projekt